# Calculate the weighted distance from a modified distance matrix

Tags: r, distance, distance-matrix

I got a modified distance matrix where I want to use the transformed (normalized) distance in the creation of a variable. Below, I have some code that produces an example data.

```
set.seed(12)

size <- sample(100:1000, 7)
var <- c("V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9")
dist <- matrix(runif(100), nrow = 7, ncol = 7)
diag(dist) <- 0

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(var, size, dist))
```

This leads to a dataset looking like this:

```
  var size                  V3                V4                 V5                V6                V7                 V8                V9
1  V3  549                   0 0.264918377622962  0.787836347473785 0.439429325051606 0.941087544662878   0.97763589094393 0.774718186818063
2  V4  445  0.0228777434676886                 0 0.0978530396241695 0.669819295872003 0.693911424372345  0.197649595327675 0.394586439244449
3  V5  435 0.00832482660189271 0.457607151241973                  0 0.240883231163025 0.843702238984406  0.844225987326354 0.361513090785593
4  V6  346   0.392697197152302 0.540707547217607  0.217823043232784                 0 0.384644460165873 0.0950279189273715 0.421090044546872
5  V7  958   0.813880559289828 0.665679829893634  0.267943592974916 0.882756386883557                 0  0.381151003297418 0.322011524345726
6  V8  273    0.37624845537357 0.112698937533423  0.504767951788381 0.814063254510984  0.58848182996735                  0 0.552160830702633
7  V9  552   0.380812183720991  0.21836716751568  0.188586926786229 0.633264608215541 0.530477509833872  0.152623838977888                 0
```

The data consists of several variables indicating on the distance between the `var` and different points, where the column called `V3`, `V4`, and so on, is the other point, i.e. `var == V4` distance to `V5` is denoted by the column called `V5`. `Size` denotes the size.

What I want to do is to calculate the weighted sum of `distance`, where the distance is weighted according to the size of the other point. See the formula below:
[image]

where **Si** is the size of unit *i*, (the variable is called `size`). **Di** is the normalized distance between one point (i.e. column `var3`, `var4`, `var5`...) to the **i** th point, and the summation is over all **k** units.

For example, **Di** can be the distance from the given point `V3` to `V4` (`0.264918377622962`), and then the **Si** is the `size` of `var == V4` (i.e. `445`)

How do I perform this calculation when my data looks like this?

Thanks!

Comment: @Onyambu I think `WS` here is a scalar that is the size for a single point that is weighted according to its distance to all other points, so the subscripts represent all the other points and we only require a single index for each `WS` considered. That's how I interpret it - perhaps the OP could clarify?

Comment: @AllanCameron I'm sorry for not being clear enough. But, yes. Your interpretation is right. How can I edit the post so that becomes more clear?

Comment: @AllanCameron I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I realized I misread one part of your previous comment. 

Your interpretation is almost right. WS  is a scalar that is the summed weighted distance from one point to all other points, weighted according to the size of the other point. So WS is, e.g. the distance from V3 to V4  weighted according to the size of V4, the distance from V3 to V5 should is weighted according to the size of V5, and so on for all other points. Then sum this and that's the WS value for V3. Does that make sense?

How can I edit the post so that becomes more clear?

Comment: I think I understand. Can you check my update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

Working column-wise, we divide the `size` of each point by its distance from the column representing the point in question (1:7). Obviously we exclude the diagonal. Summing the result gives us the weighted size for that point

```r
set.seed(12)

size <- sample(100:1000, 7)
var <- c("V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9")
dist <- matrix(runif(49), nrow = 7, ncol = 7)
diag(dist) <- 0

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(var, size, dist))

df$WS <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), 
         function(i) sum(as.numeric(as.character((df[[2]][-i]))) / 
                         as.numeric(as.character(df[[i + 2]][-i]))))

df$WS
#> [1] 75937.840 10052.202 13876.181  6011.826  4144.254 13099.493  7330.831
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Went through your code manually and found one problem. I'm not really sure how to solve this in R. If we have two points, (V3 & V4) according to your code, we take the distance from V3 to V4, divide it with the size of V3, & assign that as WS to V4. 

I want it to take that distance, divide it with the size of V4, and assign it to V3. 

Example: There are 445 people living in region A &549 in region B. The transformed distance from A to B is 0.1693. When creating the WS value for A, we divide the distance between A and B by the population size of B (549). WS is (549/0.164) 3242.764

Comment: @ecl no, that's not right. Suppose `i` is 1 (in the first iteration). Then `df[[2]][-i]` is `df[[2]][-1]`, which is the same as `df$size[2:7]`. Similarly,  `df[[i + 2]][-i]` is the same as `df$V3[2:7]`. That means the calculation for column V3 does not include anything from the row with V3, and starts on V4's row, so the calculation the code does is the calculation you are describing. The first value will be `df$size[2]/df$V3[2]` which is V4's size divided by the distance from V3 to V4, as you describe.

Comment: Yes you are right! I'm sorry. I realized that the data I provided confused me since it gives two different distances for the same distance. (V4 to V3 have one value while V3 to V4 have another). So that's why I thought something was wrong. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I greatly appreciate it :D